# Where is openvpn access server port defined?

Tags: openvpn

I installed openvpn access server in my VPS and worked fine last time.

A while I didn't use the `vpn` and I noticed the port for access server is changed from `943` to `914`.

Maybe I just forgot I reconfigured it. But I couldn't find out where is the config file.

```
cd /etc/openvpn
ack 914
```

The command above returns nothing. Where is the port defined?

Comment: You mean on the client side ? It depends how you run openvpn, if it's through your distro's gui check your settings, otherwise it's usually something like `openvpn --config client.ovpn` and you have a client.ovpn file somewhere...

Comment: I'm using `open vpn access server` that makes easier the configuration of `openvpn`, that was the explation. https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/section-faq-openvpn-as/general/133-what-is-openvpn-access-server.html But this script solved my problem https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install I don't use the `OpenVPN AS` anymore. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: For openvpn-as:**

The `openvpn-as` port is logged in the file `/usr/local/openvpn_as/init.log`
You can find the port for example using `grep`:

```
grep -rE "([0-9]{1,3}\.?){4}:[0-9]+/" /usr/local/openvpn_as
```

The configuration of `openvpn-as` is handled by a script:

```
/usr/local/openvpn_as/bin/ovpn-init
```

**For openvpn:**

The openvpn server port is defined using the `port` directive either in a config file like this:

```
port 1194
```

or when `openvpn` is directly invoked from the command line with the parameter `--port`:

```
openvpn --port 1194 [...other parameters...]
```

On Linux the config should normally have the file ending `.conf` and be placed in:

```
/etc/openvpn
```

On Windows the config should normally have the file ending `.ovpn` and be placed in:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config\
```

But it can also be located any where else and specified when invoked from the command line like this:

```
openvpn --config /home/user/server.conf
```

To find the config file of your running openvpn process, you can use the command

```
ps fawux | grep openvpn
```

which should return the command line arguments passed to openvpn including the path to the config file. for example:

```
/usr/sbin/openvpn --daemon ovpn-tun --status /run/openvpn/tun.status 10 --cd /etc/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/openvpn-config.conf
```

where `openvpn-config.conf` is your config file.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but my question was not about `openvpn` itself, it's about `openvpn access server`. https://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/section-faq-openvpn-as/general/133-what-is-openvpn-access-server.html But I decided not to use it anymore. With this script my problem solved. https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your question carefully. I updated my answer with how to find the port on `openvpn-as`. The only other location where I found the port is `/usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/config.json`. You can try to update it manually, but I am not sure if it works.